# What's the frequency v power relationship of an oscillator + transmitter?

Tags: power, rf, frequency, oscillator

I'm starting with the assumption that a higher frequency EM wave is more energetic than a lower frequency one and thus requires more energy (and thus more power) to transmit.

In my naive model of a transmitter, there's an oscillator circuit, an amplifier and an antenna. It doesn't seem to be the case that there's a proportional relationship between frequency and power in an [oscillator circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator) so am assuming that the extra power must be consumed by either the amplifier or antenna circuitry.

Is the power consumed by an oscillator circuit not proportional to the frequency of oscillation, ceteris paribus?

In what stage of the generation/transmission of higher frequency EM waves does the extra power get consumed ?

Assuming wide enough bandwidth in the amplifier + antenna for the frequencies under consideration (ie 3 dB point is far enough out or ideal no parasitic system), where does the extra power get consumed to justify conservation of energy and Einstein-Planck (E=hv)?

Comment: Oscillators themselves consist of amplifiers that are required to maintain a positive feedback condition. This is likely where the energy will be consumed.

Comment: The amplifier can be considered discrete - separate from the oscillator. Yes, the amplifier consumes power but that's the case for all frequencies. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: [Higher frequencies (shorter wavelengths) have more energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation)

Comment: You are mixing up different ideas. Photons of higher frequency radiation have more energy per photon. But the power of an EM signal is strictly a matter of its voltage and current. All sine waves of the same amplitude have the same ability to do work (as long as we are in the theoretical world where we ignore parasitic losses and such).

Imagine a transmitter in free space. When it transmits at a power of 1W, then no matter the frequency, the Voltage amplitude of the EM wave will be the same. At higher frequencies, the photons may be more energetic, but there will be fewer of them.

Comment: In RF spectrum, the wave INTENSITY could be proportional to the square of the amplitude (either E or M field), because particles in this frequencies have less energy than the kinetic energy of atoms and electrons due to their thermal motion. "Most energetic" you mean the energy of some eV obtaned as reaction energy. In higher frequencies (i.e light) the intensity of the wave is the energy per photon times the number of photons per unit area. The entropy paradox explained by the intensity and phase of photons.

Comment: Yes there are different ideas at work here, hence the question. The voltage and current of a 'signal' in circuit get converted by an antenna into EM waves whose power is not measured either by voltage or current but by E & B fields. The thought of a fewer number of higher energy photons did occur to me but it's not entirely satisfying. @mkeith your comment seems to imply that the frequency of the oscillator is unrelated to the frequency of the EM wave transmitted.

Comment: @mkeith I'm impressed that you're able to figure out what I think about photons and waves. Please provide an answer if you have one. Your first comment was somewhat useful, the latter two less so.

Comment: @shridhara. Please remove the classic physics from your mind, try to imagine a pre-roasted chicken in your favour fast-food, then calculate why a 500W of red light it is less efficient of a magnetron (builded on a MWoven) with same output power, in order to re-heat your meal...

Comment: There's no paradox (or mysticism) implied in the question. The question assumes extra energy is consumed to generate higher frequency EM waves. If that's true (which nobody has so far convincingly contradicted) the question simply is where in the process of generation/transmission does that extra energy get input ? It's not in the oscillator itself as that doesn't have proportional frequency dependence.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer I found most convincing was on the [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146053/whats-the-relationship-between-input-power-and-intensity-frequency-of-radiate/146089#146089).

The argument is that for given input power there are fewer resistive losses when driving an emitter/antenna at higher frequency resulting in higher intensity (Poynting vector) of a higher frequency emitter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an engineers and not a physics forum, so I will try to give a simple answer.

A radio (electrical) oscillator working like a fast switch opening and closing a circuit those producing a series of pulses (very simplified). It does not charge atoms to change their energy level and then to release photons that have energy related with their frequency. So in radio oscillator it is not necessary to add power as the frequency increase.
Few meters from an ordinary RF antenna you will have EM radiation or photons with very low energy (not intensity!) hundred thousand lower than a UV photon.

But in –let’s say- X-ray tube yes you have to increase the voltage (even DC) to accelerate electrons and to obtain high-energy photons from specific metals (i.e. 100kV for 100eV photon).

It is clearly different mechanism.

In any case don’t mix-up classical electrodynamics and quantum mechanics.

Comment: Your earlier comment about intensity is the only plausible explanation. For a given level of power, higher (lower) frequency waves will be generated at a lower (higher) intensity.

Comment: I don't see a difference between generating higher frequency radio waves versus generating x-rays. Higher frequency is higher frequency and requires more power to generate a certain given intensity.

Comment: According to your reasoning mind, a hanfull of an enriched radioactive material, it is not possible to have this enormous power (nuclear), because there is no another higher power to stimulate this. In pyrotechnics this is we are called "ignition". The formula E=hv confuse you. Use the precice one v=(E2-E1)/h which E1 and E2 is the energy levels of electrons, and h the Plank's constant off cource. Regarding RF ordinary frequencies, please keep in mind that the thermal noise covers the photon's small energy on this frequencies.

Comment: Forget about E=h\$\nu\$. Even for an electric dipole, power radiated goes like \$ \omega^{4} \$ so definitely frequency dependent. That extra power must come from the driving process - not the oscillator circuit so has to be the amplifier/antenna.

Comment: Forget about this...forget about that....I hope you will come back after some decades with a better explanation, that may be you allraedy have

Comment: Wow you lot get tetchy even at the slightest dis-agreement. In this case I was taking your advice of not confusing classical em and quantum mechanics so I said forget the latter (qm) and consider an example of electric dipole from classical em. I still don't have an answer but have found some additional information - that an antenna has gain proportional to frequency.

Comment: Definitely antenna adding a gain, but there is not answer to your question, unless you change the question, since this gain it is a  result of beam consentraion and no extra power needed.